# How do decorate mux subrouter similar to http.Handler?

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm using gorilla/mux as HTTP router. While all routes should be gzip-compressed,
I'd like to decorate the `/api` routes with JSON headers. I have the handler:

```
// jsonHandler decorates response with JSON and CORS headers
func jsonHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
        // w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

and the router:

```
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
router.HandleFunc("/", h.mkIndexHandler(mc))

// api
api := router.PathPrefix("/api").Subrouter()
api.HandleFunc("/last", h.allValuesHandler(mc, mc.Current))
...

srv := http.Server{
    Addr:    url,
    Handler: handlers.CompressHandler(router),
}
```

Is it possible to "decorate" the api `SubRouter` with the json headers other than adding them to each individual handler function similar to what `handlers.CompressHandler` does for the mux root router?

Comment: That's what middleware is for. See [`Use()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.Use).

Comment: Thanks. Duplicate once you know that you want to use a middleware :)